# How to get 1st field of a file only when 2nd field matches a string?

Tags: linux, awk

How to get 1st field of a file only when 2nd field matches a given string?

#cat temp.txt

```
Ankit   pass
amit    pass
aman    fail
abhay   pass
asha    fail
ashu    fail
```

---

```
cat temp.txt | awk -F"\t" '$2 == "fail" { print $1 }'*
```

gives no output

Comment: Welcome to SO, thank you for showing your efforts in form of code. Your subject says 5th field you want to print and check 7th field but your code says its 2nd field you are checking. Could you please do add more clear description in your post and let us know then.

Comment: are you sure that your second field is exactly equal to "fail"? There are no extra spaces involved, maybe there is a hidden carriage return (CR) from a windows file (check with `cat -vET file`. Maybe due to the tab as a field separator, your field is actually something like `"fail___"` (underscore represents space)`. Hence there are many possibilities here of what might have gone wrong.

Comment: Remove the `-F"\t"` and the stray `*` at the end of the command. For the data shown, it should work with tabs or spaces in the input.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to work fine when I remove the `*` at the end

```
cat temp.txt | awk -F"\t" '$2 == "fail" { print $1 }'
```

The other thing to check is if your file is using tab or spaces. My copy/paste of your data file copied spaces, so I needed this line:

```
cat temp.txt | awk '$2 == "fail" { print $1 }'
```

The other way of doing this is with grep:

```
cat temp.txt | grep fail$ | awk '{ print $1 }'
```

Comment: Yes, there are thousand other ways to do it, But it is bugging me, why i am not getting any result with "cat temp.txt | awk -F"\t" '$2 == "fail" { print $1 }'" still

Comment: Ankit did you try the suggestion you got [in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62835076/how-to-get-1st-field-of-a-file-only-when-2nd-field-matches-a-string/62842830#comment111116677_62835076) from @kvantour 5 hours before you posted that comment? I think he was on the right track.

Comment: Check to see if your file is using tabs or spaces. If using spaces try `cat temp.txt | awk '$2 == "fail" { print $1 }'`. (example now fixed), or else remove the `*` from the end of your command.

Comment: Awk can open files just fine by itself, see http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html.

Comment: I have used an alternate @james the recommended one still is giving any output

Answer (score 0):

Another syntax with awk:

```
awk '$2 ~ /^faild$/{print $1}' input_file
```

A deleted 'cat' command.

- ^  start string
- $ end string

It's the best way to match patten.

Comment: of course equivalent to `$2=="fail"` here (once you fix the typo), but may be useful if it wasn't a literal match.

Comment: ...'faild' or 'fail', this is just an example!

Comment: Since you're new there, I gave some feedback but cannot force you to take it.  People usually copy/paste the scripts to test, so I think it make sense to at least try to make sure it works; but again it's up to you.

Comment: There are no patterns when matching text, there are only strings and regexps. Using a regexp comparison to match a string is inefficient, fragile, and obfuscates your code so `$2 == "fail"` is better in every way than `$2 ~ /^fail$/`.

Comment: and what if we have to search for a variable rather than a literal.
suppose NAMESPACE="test"..

awk '$2 ~ /$NAMESPACE/{print $1}' input_file  will not work  ?

Comment: You can use the variable like this for example: awk '$2 ~ /^'"$NAMESPACE"'$/{print $1}' input_file

Answer (score 0):

Either:

1. Your fields are not tab-separated or
2. You have blanks at the end of the relevant lines or
3. You have DOS line-endings and so there are CRs at the end of every
   line and so also at the end of every $2 in every line (see
   [Why does my tool output overwrite itself and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45772525/1745001))

With GNU `cat` you can run `cat -Tev temp.txt` to see tabs (`^I`), CRs (`^M`) and line endings (`$`).